# An unknown error has occurred in asset reindex

Tags: craft3, assets, error, reindex

I am getting the error: An unknown error occurred for each file in a folder when I try Update Asset Indexes.  The folder is a local folder that is outside of webroot.  The files just contain json data. I have looked through Craft log files and apache log files and cannot find anything. Any ideas?

I have tried the following from other questions with the same error message and none of these made an difference.

**Deleted entire craft/storage/runtime/ folder**

[An unknown error occurred - no log entry](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30191/an-unknown-error-occurred-no-log-entry)

**Made sure no record in table assetindex has null for dateModified column**

["An unknown error occurred" in assets screen](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26463/an-unknown-error-occurred-in-assets-screen)

**Reset folder ownership**

[permissions userphotos "an unknown error occurred"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17039/permissions-userphotos-an-unknown-error-occurred)

Comment: Can you use the browser's developer console to check what's in the response body for Ajax requests running during the indexing?

Comment: I have not built any code to load the content of the files yet since I can't add them through the reindex

Comment: Symlink the folder they are in from your public web root?

Comment: I mean when you run the indexing process, your Craft install fires a bunch of Ajax requests to the server to try to index the files. Can you check the response body of those requests? If all seems normal, maybe enable devMode and try again.

Comment: it appears to be some kind of ownership / permission issue even though I reset ownership / permission on the entire folder structure.  I set it up on my work computer and it works perfectly.  Maybe I just need to clone the repo again in a new folder and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the json file in the browser. There are chance of showing unknown error when the path of the json file is missing in Asset Index.

Comment: The files are outside of the webroot so I can't access them from the browser